# Can't connect C# application to Oracle 11g

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 stumbling problem:

1) Which is the correct port number?

This is the link when I run my Oracle 11g:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1:786646867589622
```

I'm confused as to my port number is 1521, 8080 or 4950?

2) ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

This is my connection string:

```
string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
             + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + server + ")(PORT=" + port +     ")))"
             + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)));"
             + "User Id=" + uid + ";Password=" + password + ";";
```

And my connection parameters are:

```
DB obj2 = new Oracle("localhost", "1521", "system", "dada050909");
```

Am unable to connect and was displayed the error 12514.

Please help - I'm not very familiar with C# and Oracle. Have been stuck for quite some time.

Comment: Why `SERVICE_NAME=ORCL`, and not `SERVICE_NAME=" + sid + ...`??
Check this resource http://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/ora-12514/

Comment: Yes I managed to solve it by changing my service_name to XE